# How to remove all special prices for a specific customer group

Tags: magento2, database, sql, delete

I accidentally uploaded special prices for an erroneous group of customers.

How to remove all special prices for a group of customers, not login

`(customer_group_id = 0)` for all products and items from the table `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`

Help please with writing a request!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM el_magento.catalog_product_entity_tier_price WHERE customer_Group_id = {your_customer_group_id};
```

This should solve your problem ;)